# Can I use an std::map with both keys and values being enum classes in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, enums

I need a way of mapping C++11 `enum classes` to other `enum classes`. Let's say I have these C++11 style enums:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Foobar
{
public:

    enum class Lecture
    {
        COMP_SCI,
        PHYSICS,
        CHEMISTRY,
        BIOLOGY,
        PSYCHOLOGY,
        MODERN_ART,
        PHILOSOPHY,
        SOCIOLOGY
    };

    enum class Day
    {
        MONDAY,
        TUESDAY,
        WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY,
        FRIDAY,
        SATURDAY,
        SUNDAY
    };
};


void test_enum_class_to_enum_class_std_map()
{
    std::map<Foobar::Lecture, Foobar::Day> lectureToDayMap;

    lectureToDayMap.insert(Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI, Foobar::Day::MONDAY);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test_enum_class_to_enum_class_std_map();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way of mapping from one enum class to another?

I want something like

`std::map<Foobar::Lecture, Foobar::Day> lectureToDayMap;`

If this isn't possible, am I able to convert from an `int` to an `enum class` and vice versa so I can just use a `std::map<int, int>` map and convert to `int` to insert, and back to an `enum class` to retrieve a value?

Here is the compilation error When I try the first method:

```
test_cpp11_enums.cpp: In function ‘void test_enum_class_to_enum_class_std_map()’:
test_cpp11_enums.cpp:51:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<Foobar::Lecture, Foobar::Day>::insert(Foobar::Lecture, Foobar::Day)’
     lectureToDayMap.insert(Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI, Foobar::Day::MONDAY);
                                                                          ^
test_cpp11_enums.cpp:51:74: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61:0,
                 from test_cpp11_enums.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:594:7: note: std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = Foobar::Lecture; _Tp = Foobar::Day; _Compare = std::less<Foobar::Lecture>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Foobar::Lecture, Foobar::Day> >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const Foobar::Lecture, Foobar::Day> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<const Foobar::Lecture, Foobar::Day>]
       insert(const value_type& __x)
```

Thank you for your time :)

**Edit 1: Fixed a missing comma**

**Edit 2: Added the compilation error I get**

**Edit 3: Added the full source of what I am trying out**

**Edit 4: No new code or anything, just an apology to everyone for misunderstanding how these posts work. I have a tough time understanding compilation errors still and I didn't find exactly what I was looking for in Google. I thought it might be easier to ask directly about what I wanted and perhaps get an explanation on how class enums work (or don't) with maps. I will keep playing with my test source and keep looking on Google. Sorry for irritating you all :(**

**Edit 5:**
You guys were kind enough to show me where my error was, thank you. I didn't see that `sdt::map`'s `insert` function didn't take the key and value as arguments. At first I thought the error meant that no `std::map` named insert exists, and when I checked that it does online, I somehow missed looking at the parameters, becoming convinced this was something to do with `enum classes`, since I never used them before.

Comment: Have you tried to actually do this?

Comment: In less time than asking a question, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1dd725264f80250

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP is too lazy to even try out what he wants to do before asking a question.

Comment: @AlexM., Not my missing comma.

Comment: @chris Whoops, sorry, didn't spot it in OP's message.

Comment: You insert a `std::pair` in a `std::map`. <a>std::map::insert</a>(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/)

Comment: @Landon, This problem has nothing to do with `enum class`.

Comment: @Praetorian - I tried it but I didn't paste the compilation error in the original question. This is completely my fault. I am having a hard time figuring out what the error means and have suspected it is because what I wanted is not possible, so I phrased my question in that way. My apologies once again.

Comment: @Landon You need to post the code for where the compilation error is, i.e. `test_enum_class_to_enum_class_std_map()`

Comment: @B... - I did so just now. I checked http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert and set does indeed have an insert() method, so I don't know why it is saying "no matching function call". Hypothesis is that it is because I cannot use class enums in a map.

Comment: Again, in order to insert `{Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI, Foobar::Day::MONDAY}` in your map you have to insert it like a pair (i.e., `yourMap.insert(std::make_pair(Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI, Foobar::Day::MONDAY))`) [std::map::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/). the compiler complains that there's no overload to insert what you want in the way that you want.

Comment: @40two - Thank you so much for explaining it. I feel blind right now that I missed it. I am new to C++ and didn't understand the error fully. I thought the compiler was complaining that no function of that name existed, so when I checked to see if map has an insert function, and saw it, I didn't look close enough at the parameters. I was completely convinced that the problem was with the enum classes, and perhaps something to do with inability to be hashed or something. I was looking in the completely wrong place.

Comment: @Landon, in your case using `operator[]` would be much less ugly than `insert()`. `lectureToDayMap[Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI] = Foobar::Day::MONDAY;`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/.

Comment: @B... Thank you for the suggestion, I saw it a few minutes ago. I am new to C++ and didn't see that it had that operator implemented. I am working on a few different files in different languages at the moment and am getting their container object APIs mixed up.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map
*std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys*.   Therefore you must insert a pair.

Replace

```
 lectureToDayMap.insert(Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI, Foobar::Day::MONDAY);
```

by

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI, Foobar::Day::MONDAY));
```

or better

```
lectureToDayMap[Foobar::Lecture::COMP_SCI] = Foobar::Day::MONDAY;
```